# Error Reading from Database - Moodle

Tags: php, database, moodle

currently we are experiencing the 'Error Reading from Database' issue with our Moodle site. We've established this is not due to a recent Upgrade and are unsure of the troubleshooting steps to take for this fix.

Can anyone advise of the troubleshooting steps we can take to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Moodle did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: Is there a Stack Trace? If so, please edit the question and add the Stack Trace.

Comment: Where is your database?  Is it up? Can the web server see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error does not tell us exactly what is going on, but you can try this:

Open the file: `/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php` and change `@@default_storage_engine` to `@@storage_engine`.

Hope that helps!